# How to do Mass Profile Updates

Tags: profile, configuration

I have a configuration question.

We have 5 profiles : P1, P2, P3, P4, and P5

1 Custom Object : Object1.

I want to grant the "Edit" permission to the P1 profile for Object1, and "Real All" for the rest of the profiles.

So I gave the "Modify All" permission to P1 but my question is whether I have to go each of the other profiles and grant them "Read All" or if there is a way to give to do them all at once.

Here we have only P2, P3, P4, P5 so it's possible to do them manually, but it'd be pain if we had 100 profiles.

Comment: Anyone who happens to get this comment:    3 years later, is this still the case?  Metadata or clone and manually edit?   :-/     We're using ROOTSTOCK (both ERP and Financials which isn't even released yet).   That means we have over 730 objects in our Org (and we're not deployed yet).   I'd like to believe someone has created either an external App, a REALLY friendly Spreadsheet, or an AppExchange solution........  but my search has been in vain.   HELP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled enhanced profiles you can easily create a list view for profiles and mass edit them.
To activate enhanced profiles you need to have the "manage Users" and customize Applications permissions.

After that you can activate enhanced profiles in the user interface setup.
Just check the "Enable Enhanced Profile List Views" Checkbox.

Now you can create profile list views with mass edit functionality.

Here the link i found:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_inline_editing.htm&language=en_US

Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Tarek, As much as we like answers, usually, one liners are not accounted as good/helpful answers - usually. Posting a URL for an external resource is considered as such as well. Feel free to add more content, elaborate and give examples where you think they can help.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

- Create and configure P1 first, and then **clone** it as many times you need to create P2, P3... P100
- Use **metadata API** and your favorite text editor to perform a search and replace

The first option is a little bit silly, I know, but I've solved a lot of problems just cloning an existing profile and do the rest of the changes manually.

The second one requires that you connect some IDE, like Force.com IDE or Mavensmate. It's a pretty easy process and will save a lot of time.

Example of a profile file section with the permissions:

```
<objectPermissions>
    <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
    <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
    <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
    <allowRead>true</allowRead>
    <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
    <object>Your_Object__c</object>
    <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
</objectPermissions>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want, can use a tool I has developed https://github.com/OscarIuliano/ProfiliSFDC

It can help you ti add massive permissione in your profile, or create massive custommetadata in your repository.